# importing classes in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im working on a group project in react and were all pretty new to the experience. We run into some problems but where able to get by on our own. One of my friends suggested stack overflow in case we get really stuck. Since its our school project were working on it while at home but we both have limited access to the internet so cant really utilize online resources as much as we would like.

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './ViewJobsList.css';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';



class A extends React.Component {...};
class B extends React.Component {...};

export {A,B};
```

This is for our App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { A, B } from "./app.js"


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

this is our index.js

the last import is grayed out and not being read. im not sure why my group mate said that it should work since it was suggested to do so here.

[here is our directory basic nothings changed so im not sure what our problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbG3C.png)

this is the error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Zyq.png)

Answer (score 0):

typo : `import { A, B } from "./App.js";`

Comment: ah i didnt notice i corrected it. But i editted my question to show my error message thank you in advance as wel

Comment: Okay the error is because of this line `import App from "./App";`.

In JavaScript, you can import things by two ways : by `default` exports, and by `named` exports.

Here, A and B are exported individually (with `export {A,B};`, which is the same as if you would just write :
`export class A extends React.Component {...};`

Comment: This is a `named` export.
To import a `named` export, you should use brackets :
`import { A } from './App.js';`

A default export is something exported like `export default A`.

So when you write `import App from "./App";`, you tell JavaScript to import something from App.js that's exported using `default` keyword, which does not exists here.

Comment: So you probably just need to remove `import App from "./App";` and render A or B :
ReactDOM.render(<A />, document.getElementById("root"));
serviceWorker.unregister();

Comment: Im getting an error wherer my ReactDOM is undef sadly

Answer (score 0):

In this line you are importing default export in app.js file which you don't have.

```js
import App from "./App";
```

That's why you are getting this error.

See this implementation.

app.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from './ViewJobsList.css';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

class A extends React.Component {...};
class B extends React.Component {...};
class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
     return (
       <>
        <A />
        <B />
       </>
     );
   }
}
export {A,B}; //Actually, you use only <App /> component in index.js no need to export 
              //these components but you can export also these subcomponents. 
export default App; //this means you have a default export in this file so you can import
                    //this App component without using curly brackets as you try above.
```

index.js,

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App,{A,B} from "./App"; //again no need to import A and B here but you can.
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This solves your problem but I strongly recommend you to have seperate .js files for each component. You can still combine these components in one file by using 'export ... from ..' syntax.